# jquery ui button icon not centered in firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, icons

I've this button

```
$('#galery .buttonClose').button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-closethick",
        text: false
    }
});
```

css :

```
  #galery .buttonClose{position: absolute; top: 3px; right: 3px; height: 30px; width: 30px;}
```

It's working fine on Chrome the icon is centered on the button but in Firefox the icon is completly down

jsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/nDMV8/2/

This seems to be a common bug in jQuery UI i think they should plan something when you try to do a **button with no text** to set the css correctly and working in all browsers. Like they show all the icons on their themes page (bottom): http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Please post the HTML and a jsFiddle would also help.

Comment: all my html is generated in js but i will try to reproduce this in jsFiddle

Comment: seems to be a common bug thought!

Comment: Doesn't look centered in Chrome to me.

Comment: yes you right, but the problem is more on the vertical line, look on chrome is fine and firefox completly down

Comment: You also have your `text: false` option in the wrong place, it should be:                                                                       {
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-closethick"
        },
        text: false
    }

Comment: seems to be the solution :)
i just had to set the height at 32px and fixed
Post it as a solution and i will accept it, thanks again i didn't pay enough attention to my js code, my bad...
But it will be really cool if they could detect if there is no text in the jQuery ui framework directly and set it to false, just one line of code ;)

Comment: by the way, it's weird because i didn't had in error in the console, may be there is another "text" property on icon then... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have your text: false option in the wrong place, it should be:

```
  { icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" }, text: false }
```

**Thanks to jmoerdyk**

Then i just had to set the height at *32px* and fixed !

Answer (score 2):

```
#galery .buttonClose{
    top: 3px;
    right:3px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width: 35px;
}
```

An example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nDMV8/3/). Tested in chrome, ff and ie.
​

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect for the height but i still have an issue when i try to reduce the width, with this result is pretty good
#galery .buttonClose{position: absolute; top: 3px; right:3px; height: auto; padding-top: 19px; width: 32px;}
but still not perfect in Chrome this time just 1 pixel

Comment: i will wait a few hours if someone come with the perfect solution, if not i will accept yours, thanks again! ;)